# Link between convergence in Probability of a supremum and a limsup

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be i.i.d rv with distribution function F. Then, if we know for $\epsilon > 0$ small, that

\begin{align}
\sup_{0<s\le1} s^{1/2+\epsilon} \Bigg| \sqrt k \bigg [ \frac{1}{\gamma} \Big(\log X_{n-[ks],n}- \log U\Big(\frac{n}{k}\Big)\Big)+\log s \bigg] - \frac{W_n(s)}{s} -\sqrt k A_0\Big(\frac{n}{k}\Big) \frac{1}{\gamma} \frac{s^{-\rho}-1}{\rho} \Bigg| \overset{P} \rightarrow 0
\end{align} 
holds for $n \rightarrow \infty$, with $k=k(n) \rightarrow \infty, k/n \rightarrow 0$, $\sqrt k A_0(n/k)=O(1)$ and some parameter $\gamma>0$, $\rho\le0$.

Furthermore,  $X_{1,n}\le X_{2,n} \le ... \le X_{n,n}$ are the nth order statistics, $U=\Big(\frac{1}{1-F}\Big)^{\leftarrow}$ is the left-continuous inverse of $1/(1-F)$, where $f^{\leftarrow}(x):=\inf\{ y: f(y) \ge x \}$ and $\{ W_n (s)\}_{s\ge0}$ is a sequence of Brownian motions. $[x]$ means $\text{floor}(x)$.

My question is:

> If we know that this convergence holds, how can we deduce that also 
>   \begin{align}
> \limsup_{0<s\le1} s^{1/2+\epsilon} \Bigg| \sqrt k \bigg [ \frac{1}{\gamma} \Big(\log X_{n-[ks],n}- \log X_{n-k,n} \Big)+\log s \bigg] - \frac{W_n(s)}{s} + W_n(1) - \sqrt k A_0\Big(\frac{n}{k}\Big) \frac{1}{\gamma} \frac{s^{-\rho}-1}{\rho} \Bigg| \overset{P} \rightarrow 0
> \end{align}

A problem I have with this is that $U(n/k)=X_{n-k,n}$ is false in general. And if we add $W_n(1)$, we are making the supremum bigger. So why is this true?

Comment: What is the limsup you are considering, already?

Comment: Anyway, the appearance of $W_n(1)$ is only logical and the proof you are after might simply follow from the fact that the first assertion is $$\sup_{0<s\leqslant1}s^{1/2+\epsilon} |Z_n(s)|\to0$$ with $$Z_n(s)=\sqrt k \bigg [ \frac{1}{\gamma} \Big(\log X_{n-[ks],n}- \log U\Big(\frac{n}{k}\Big)\Big)+\log s \bigg] - \frac{W_n(s)}{s} -\sqrt k A_0\Big(\frac{n}{k}\Big) \frac{1}{\gamma} \frac{s^{-\rho}-1}{\rho} $$ and that the expression in the limsup is then $$s^{1/2+\epsilon} |Z_n(s)-Z_n(1)|$$